# In the two-way data binding, modifying the data value in the viewModel flow.collect block fails to reflect on the UI

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-edittext, kotlin-flow

When I use two-way data binding, I change the data value in MutableStateFlow.collect, but the result is not reflected on the UI.

login_fragfment:

```xml
    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.myapp.ui.login.LoginViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        ... >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user_id"
            android:layout_width="198dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:autofillHints="username"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_input"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@={viewModel.id}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_logo"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

viewModel:

```
    val id = MutableStateFlow(Preferences.userId)
    val password = MutableStateFlow("")
    val isEnable = MutableStateFlow(false)

    init {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            id.value = "user1在这里"
            password.value = "abcdefg"
        }

        if (StoreRepository.isLoggedIn) {
            appNavController.navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_downloadFragment)
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            merge(id, password).collect {
                id.value = filterMatchRegex(id.value, "[\\x22-\\xfe]+") 
                isEnable.value = id.value.isNotBlank() && password.value.isNotBlank()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Filter parts that do not match the regex
    */
    fun filterMatchRegex(input: String, pattern: String): String {
        val regex = Regex(pattern)
        var output = ""
        regex.findAll(input).forEach { 
            output += it.value
        }
        return output
    }
```

Is it because the value of the flow cannot be modified in the collect block？
will it cause an infinite loop?
If you have a good way to display the UI on the EditText after regex filtering under the premise of two-way binding, please let me know, thank you!

The initially displayed data is "user1", not "user1在这里".
I try to enter it multiple times and the UI shows the value I actually entered, what I want is the value that was processed after I entered it.
For example, if you enter `abcd12345你好啊`, it will display `abcd12345`.
but now, if you enter `abcd12345你好啊`, it will display `abcd12345你好啊`.

Answer (score 0):

Two-way databinding only works as expected if you set `lifecycleOwner`.

Add this code to you fragment's `onCreateView()`:

```kotlin
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```